# Can a pure un-entangled quantum state be correlated?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, probability, correlation-functions

Is it possible for a joint probability distribution for two random variables $x$ and $y$ to be independent, i.e  $P(x,y)$ = $P(x)P(y)$, but the mean values of distributions of $x$ and $y$ to be correlated?

In particular, I have a case of two interacting quantum particles, whose two-particle quantum state is a pure unentangled state, thus, $|\psi(x_{1},x_{2},t)|^{2}$ = $|\psi_{1}(x_{1},t)|^{2}|\psi_{2}(x_{2},t)|^{2}$. However, I can write the Ehrenfest equations ("Newton's laws") for the expectation values of $\hat x_{1,2}$, which turn out to be coupled equations, does this necessarily imply that the mean values of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ evaluated on a given un-entangled quantum state, are correlated?

Comment: What does it mean for the “mean values of distributions to be correlated”? Random variables can be correlated, but it doesn’t make sense for their mean values (which are just fixed numbers) to be correlated. Can you clarify with mathematical expressions what you mean?

Comment: The Ehrenfest theorem is about time-evolution and if $\psi$ is not an eigenstate of (the interacting) $H$, then it can get entangled during time evolution.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Yes, I am aware of that, but my time evolved state is not entangled.

Comment: @tparker by correlated I meant, that measuring x_{1} on a quantum system is like taking its expectation value, and the same for x_{2}, thus, if I measure x_{1} and their evolution equations are coupled, could I not get some prediction for x_{2} also? Furthermore, is correlation defined only for static variables? in my case, the joint distribution is time dependent and the time evolution equations of the mean values of distributions are coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the mean values of two variables are *coupled* doesn’t mean that the variables are *correlated*. In a purely classical system, you can obviously have equations of motion that couple together different physical quantities - but these quantities aren’t *correlated* in the precise sense of the word, because the classical quantities have deterministic values and correlation is only possible for non-constant random variables.

No, the subsystems of an unentangled pure state cannot be correlated, although the evolution of their mean values over time can be related to each other by simple equations. The correlation here does not refer to a time-average, but to a statistical average over many hypothetical measurements of the state at a fixed point in time.

Comment: Just for clarification, is it possible for two systems, say classical only, to evolve via coupled stochastic equations, and the distribution of random variables of the two systems, at an instant of time t, to not be correlated?

Comment: @Paranoid Yep. Just give each particle its own probability cloud, centered around its classical point trajectory, that isn’t affected by the other particle’s location.